# Problem when rendering javascript with PHP V8JS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, node-modules, v8js

I have this code to render a javascript code with PHP and V8JS but it doesn't work. Does anyone know where the problem is?

```
<?php

$v8 = new V8Js();
$code = file_get_contents('index2.js');
$result = $v8->executeString( $code );
var_dump($result);
?>
```

index2.js

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent); // "Hello world"
```

The error that occurs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught V8JsScriptException: V8Js::compileString():1: No module loader in index.php on line 6
```

I imagine the problem is in the require of the node module jsdom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to require a module, you must register a module loader with `setModuleLoader()` (see the [V8Js API](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js#php-api) and [this post](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/issues/59#issuecomment-27643141)).

You can do something like this:

```php
$v8 = new V8Js();
$v8->setModuleLoader(function($path) {
    return file_get_contents($path);
});
```

Of course you will need to adjust the code to load the file from the correct directory.